# Should I use Object Initiallization Syntax or regular Object Instantiation?

Tags: c#, initialization, instance

I'm currently reading *Pro C# 5.0 and the .NET 4.5 Framework* and have just stumbled on "Object Initialization Syntax."

I read that it can invoke any constructor, but if the parameters represent the same value types, then it's pointless. I may not be saying this correctly, so let me give an example.

```
//Assume that the custom constructor for Point() takes int X and int Y.
//The X and Y value would still be 100, regardless of what the constructor says.
Point pt = new Point(10, 18) { X = 100, Y = 100 };
```

However, it shines best when using two different types, such as if the constructor represented Color and the OIS represented X and Y values.

```
Point redPoint = new Point(PointColor.Red) { X = 90, Y = 20 };
```

Now my question is, say that I wasn't taking any parameters, is there a logical benefit to using Object Initialization Syntax? In the book it says that OIS allows you to initialize any accessible field, but couldn't that all be done in a constructor?
I would appreciate if one of you could give an example of when it's not possible to initialize in a constructor.
He didn't go past giving the example with color and it didn't give an example other than the color for when it's useful.

Comment: Honestly, this is one of those things that depend on your own personal style. There is no right or wrong answer here. Use whatever you like. Object initialisation only concerns accessing properties of an instance. So whatever the constructor takes (nothing or x number of parameters) it does not matter really.

Comment: Consider this, with object initialization, it is a single expression. You can set up as many properties as you need without creating constructor overloads to support what you want to initialize. Something you probably wouldn't want for DTOs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My own preference whether to use variable of constructor or not is such:

- If class makes sense only if the variable is initialized, I always initialize variable in a constructor parameter. This ensures that you cannot initialize a class which makes no sense.
- If there are some variables that can be either initialized or not initialized I almost never put them to constructor parameters and initialize them using object initializers.

In the case with `Point` class, it makes no sense to have a class with not initialized values, so values `X` and `Y` should be passed to the class in a constructor. However, color is not mandatory, so in this case I would initialize it like this:

```
Point redPoint = new Point(90, 20) { PointColor = Color.Red};
```

Answer (score 1):

Object Initialization Syntax makes life easier when consuming a class.  Take below for example.  Imagine all of the constructors that would have to be defined to handle the situations below.  Using OIS, the consumer has the ability to be flexible, and still have the benefit of initializing in one line.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public int Property2 { get; set; }
    public string Property3 { get; set; }
}

var myClass1 = new MyClass() { Property1 = "a" };
var myClass2 = new MyClass() { Property1 = "a", Property2 = 1 };
var myClass3 = new MyClass() { Property1 = "a", Property2 = 1, Property3 = "b" };
var myClass4 = new MyClass() { Property1 = "a", Property3 = "b" };
```

Comment: I agree with your answer. For example, if you have a constructor that takes a string to initialize Property1, how do you provide another constructor that initializes Property3? The OIS syntax is just syntactic sugar but its elegance and simplicity shines

Answer (score 0):

As long as it's your class, go ahead and create the constructors that make sense. But you may have classes that you cannot influence because they come from a third party library or the .NET Framework itself. Then, object initialization syntax is making it easier.

This:

```
Point redPoint = new Point(PointColor.Red) { X = 90, Y = 20 };
```

is just shorthand for this:

```
Point redPoint = new Point(PointColor.Red);

redPoint.X = 90;
redPoint.Y = 20;
```

Answer (score 0):

Object Initialization syntax is pure syntactic sugar... It's sole purpose is to supposedly make code easier to write, and read. So it's up to you, if you want to use it or not. Under the cover, the code which is generated looks exactly like how you would manually write it, if this compiler feature didn't exist.

As for constructors, ability to use object initializer should not persuade any developer to design their constructor poorly. The question should **not** be, `if all of it can be done in constructor`. The question should always be, `what set of constructors make most sense for a given class (imagining object initialization didn't exist).` and the rest is up to personal preference of the user of that class.

Comment: Hmm. I do find that OIS provides a little eye candy for me, so I guess I'll stick to it.

Thanks for the response.